# Does PHP have an authenticity token like Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, token

Does PHP have its own version of the Rails authenticity token?

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
```

If not, what is the best way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: This is for CSRF protection. But CSRF protection can nowadays be done without such tokens, just with special cookie parameters. You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which does that automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When outputting to form:

```
$token = md5(time() . rand(1,100));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;

<input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?=$token;?>'/>
```

After POST:

```
if(empty($_POST['token']) || $_POST['token'] !== $_SESSION['token']){
  exit("Bad token!");
}
unset($_SESSION['token']);
```

Comment: How would you rate that against using something like recaptcha? I noticed that twitter does not use a captcha for their register forms <- hence where I got the idea...

Comment: A token protects from CSRF attacks, but captcha blocks out non-human users (and protects from CSRF). Which one are you looking for?

Comment: Both... How does twitter get away with it?

Comment: @mtokoly They could be also using services like Akismet to match IPs and see if it matches

Comment: @Booski It looks like `$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));` is a better solution if you want a random token: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910814/best-practice-to-generate-random-token-for-forgot-password/29137661#29137661

Using `!isset` instead of `empty` and comparing with `==` instead of `===` should be enough also.

If you really want to prevent CSRF, you should check `if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))` before generating a token for your session, so a third-party website can't create a new token for your website if it already exists and invalidate the old one.