# PHP random string not actually random

Tags: php, random

I am referring to the function in the answer on [PHP random string generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289) (I have removed the default $length param).

So this code uses that function but for some reason if you run this code you will see that the strings appear multiple times in the array! So how if this is truly random can I produce these results? Do I need to amend something to produce really random strings?

```
function generateRandomString($length) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    return $randomString;
}

$i = 0;
while ($i < 5000){
    $r = '';
    $r = generateRandomString(8);
    $arr[$r][$i] = $r;
    $i++;
}

foreach ($arr as $key=>$rand){
    if(count($rand) > 1){
        echo "$key has ".count($rand).' results<br>';
    }
}
```

Example results:

```
ASCn2Db1 has 2 results
4ceXoUgh has 2 results
fCdzjEAV has 2 results
QRkXxAUJ has 2 results
```

Comment: Creating random strings does _not_ mean that the strings are guaranteed to be unique! Why should that be the case? A random algorithm does not have a history.  And actually in contrary: for short strings and many attempts you have to expect repetitions. There are only so many possible combinations...

Comment: You are saving these random strings in database. If yes, you can easily get rid of duplicate strings using while loop

Comment: True - I had just thought we were unlikely to see SO many duplicates

Comment: Generated 5000000 random strings with this algorithm on my machine and had no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually came across [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202) which seemed to answer my question. In short we use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes as a function. When run with 4 characters I got 1x collision but on 5 characters I didn't generate any. So for 8 I should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Random is not unique. Throw a dice and you will get the same number multiple times..

Comment: Fair enough but in 5000 loops and choosing from 61 elements in an 8 element string what are the odds that over 900 (which is what I saw) results will contain duplicates?? I'd say thats too high.

Comment: The human is not good at estimating probability distribution ;)

Comment: Having 900 duplicates in 5000 loops obviously cannot be called random, no matter how bad you are at estimating.

Answer (score 1):

I provided [an answer to the question you referenced in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31107425/2224584), but it's buried pretty far down under insecure answers and I'm not surprised everyone missed it.

The bug in your code that is causing so many duplicate values is here:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
```

The problem is `rand()`. If you want a high quality [PHP random string generator](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php) you need to use a better random number generator to power it. You have three good options here:

- `random_int()` (PHP 7+ only)
- [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat), which exposes a compatible interface for `random_int()` in PHP 5 projects (5.2+)
- [RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib) (PHP 5.3.2+)

TL;DR use `random_int()`, [**never `rand()` or `mt_rand()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31419246/2224584).

Even with a secure random number generator, if you have short strings and a sufficiently large sample size, [collisions are inevitable due to the birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Use longer strings and they will be far less frequent.

Answer (score -1):

I remember reading an article about this some time ago and I found [it again](http://boallen.com/random-numbers.html). 
In this article he makes a bitmap showing the random function running on Windows, not being totally random.

I would recommend you to use mt_rand() instead, you can [read more about the mt_rand() here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: No, don't use `mt_rand()`, it's just as broken as `rand()`. http://www.openwall.com/php_mt_seed/