# Alternative for openssl_random_pseudo_bytes - generate secured unique tokens

Tags: php, function, token

My server host had php version 5.2.17. I am using a random token and used openssl_random_pseudo_bytes in my function.

```
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( $length);
```

Trying to run this code from  [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string/13733588#13733588).

It is running well on my localhost with higher php version. 
Other than upgrading my server php version. What is an alternative function for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`?

**Update:** Using `mt_rand, rand or uniqid`, how can I generate secure unique tokens?
As of now, I am using this line of code:

`$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));`

`$thetoken = $token.$user_id;`

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You have to write your own routine, using something like `mt_rand()` see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php A very simple routine will do, generating characters for the length you need. Tokens should not be affected by the warning that the function does not generate cryptographically secure values.

Comment: I tried mt_rand() and rand() but it is slow and i get error run limit.

Comment: That is not what I read online: http://golearnphp.com/php-rand-vs-mt_rand-and-openssl_random_pseudo_bytes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using 5.6 but have also been looking for ways to create secure and unique tokens as I am unable to get the openssl_random_pseudo_bytes function to work. I have run across paragonie's random_compat at github which should allow you to use random_bytes() and random_int() (both only available with PHP7). They do say it should be able to be used with older 5.x versions of PHP in theory, though they do suggest updating to a current stable version of php. https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Here is a link to another stack overflow answer that suggests using random_bytes() as $token = bin2hex(random_bytes($length));

[best practice to generate random token for forgot password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910814/best-practice-to-generate-random-token-for-forgot-password)

And also the link i found suggesting paragonie's random_compat
https://akrabat.com/random_bytes-in-php-5-6-and-5-5/
https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php

Answer (score 0):

the Alternative way for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10)` is something like this `decbin(rand(0,1024))` in php 5.X

Comment: Is not even similar

Comment: `rand` is not an alternative to the OpenSSL library's CSPRNG function.`rand` is not a CSPRNG, it is not sufficiently random to use in a security context.