# Contact form password

Tags: php, passwords, contact-form

I am building a contact form using this generator... http://www.webformgenerator.eu/webformgenerator.php

My simple question is how would I add a password in the php script that would deny or allow the form to go through? I am quite new with php.

Comment: `if($input_password == $some_token) { // Submit } else { echo "Access denied!"; }` ?

Comment: here is the fiddle to access the php I generated http://jsfiddle.net/jfarr07/sf2RR/1/

Comment: @jfarr These could help http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58268-form-tokens-with-php/ **and** http://stackoverflow.com/a/2034310/1415724

Comment: @jfarr You should use http://pastebin.com/ instead for PHP code, because your fiddle is just one big clump of code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CSTjDnPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$some_token = "whatever_password";

if( isset($_POST['passwordfield']) AND $_POST['passwordfield'] == $some_token)
{
    $form = new ProcessForm();
    $form->field_rules = array(
        'field1'=>'required',
        'field2'=>'required',
        'field3'=>'required',
        'field4'=>''
    );
    $form->validate();
}
else
{
   echo "Invalid token!";
}
```