# How can i hide the id in url and just show the title?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to achieve this in Codeigniter. I have got a URL like below

```
https://www.example.com/5474/my-first-post
```

I'll be processing this URL using the id and get the blog content from this id. but I don't want to show the ID in the URL.It should be like below.

```
https://www.example.com/my-first-post
```

I'm doing this because previously I was getting the blog content using the title. But that makes the website very slow when there are a lot of rows in the database (It takes around 5 seconds roughly on the local server).Where as I tried the same using the ID. I was getting the row from database using the ID. It takes very less time like say  0.0007 seconds. Any solution to this is highly appreciated.

Comment: you can prefer this link for your reference URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723183/php-hide-id-from-being-shown-in-a-href-url

Answer (score 0):

You can use

### [uri-routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#uri-routing)

Example:

```
$route['my-first-post'] = 'your_controller/your_function';
```

Comment: how will this call the row with the id.

Comment: Hi @Jeeva if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is too hard to do routes for each url.

add a field in your table..

```
ID | url | post_title
33 | hello-world | Hello World.
```

Then use that `url` text on behalf of `id`

Comment: I'm doing it same way. But it is very slow for large table. So i wanted to do it with id and the id should not be  there in the url

Answer (score 0):

convert your numeric id using [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

Comment: Any reference please. But this will be there in the url right